# Event listener on Enter in the React-Date-Picker library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

if anyone has used this library link =>(https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-date-picker/blob/main/packages/react-date-picker/README.md), can you tell me how to make changes accepted not by onChange but by onKeyDown Enter

Here is the code

````
const SearchDates = ({ onChangeDate, date }: Props) => {
    return (
        <div className={style.search}>
            <DatePicker
                inputRef={(ref) => {
                    inputs(ref);
                }}
                calendarClassName={'calendar'}
                format="dd-MM-yyyy"
                // onChange={(value: any) => {
                //      onChangeDate(formatDate(value, fullDate));
                // }}

                onKeyDown={(event) => {
                    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
                        const value = event.target.value;
                        console.log(value);
                        onChangeDate(formatDate(value, fullDate));
                    }
                }}
                shouldCloseCalendar={({ reason }) => reason !== 'select'}
                maxDate={new Date(futureYear(1))}
                minDate={new Date(futureYear(0))}
                locale={'ru-RU'}
                dayPlaceholder={'__'}
                monthPlaceholder={'__'}
                yearPlaceholder={'____'}
                clearIcon={date ? <ClearIndicatorIcon /> : null}
                calendarIcon={<CalendarIcon />}
                showNeighboringMonth={false}
                next2Label={null}
                prev2Label={null}
                prevLabel={<ArrowLeft />}
                nextLabel={<ArrowRight />}
                view={'month'}
                formatMonthYear={(locale: string | undefined, date: Date) => formatDate(date, MonthYear) as string}
                value={date ? (isNaN(Date.parse(date)) ? undefined : new Date(date)) : undefined}
            />
        </div>
    );
};
```Anyone who has encountered this problem, can you tell me how to solve this problem.
````

Answer (score 0):

Your's approach is actually very close cause it involves one of the bugs, I believed, for `react-date-picker`. Originally, you could do something like this to make what you want (I use simple `App.tsx` as demonstration):

```
// import what you needed

type ValuePiece = Date | null;
type Value = ValuePiece | [ValuePiece, ValuePiece];

type ShouldCloseProps = {
    reason: CloseReason;
}

function App() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState<Value>(new Date());
    
    const detectIfCalendarClosed = (props: ShouldCloseProps): boolean => {
        // update: and if you don't mind also,
        // allowing someone clicking on the Icon to close.
        if (props.reason === 'buttonClick') {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <DatePicker
                onChange={value => setValue(value)}
                shouldCloseCalendar={props => detectIfCalendarClosed(props)}
                value={value} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

However, as after the any first action with the Calendar keeps open, the `reason` detected for the `Enter` key changes from `buttonClick` to regular `select` just like clicking the mouse, therefore, you need the below changes to make it work:

```
// ...same imports
// ...same types

function App() {
    // ...same useState for `value` and `setValue`
    const [isEnterPressed, setIsEnterPressed] = useState<boolean>(false);

    const detectIfCalendarClosed = (props: ShouldCloseProps): boolean => {
        let isValidCondition = false;
        if (props.reason === 'select' && isEnterPressed) {
            isValidCondition = true;
        } 

        // reset the state of `isEnterPressed` everytime after used.
        setIsEnterPressed(false);
        return isValidCondition;
    }

    const detectIfEnterPressed = (event: any): void => {
        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
            setIsEnterPressed(true);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <DatePicker
                onChange={value => setValue(value)}
                onKeyDown={e => detectIfEnterPressed(e)}
                shouldCloseCalendar={props => detectIfCalendarClosed(props)}
                value={value} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

---

Hope the above answer helps.